# How to copy elements of an array in superclass into an array in subclass in java?

Tags: java, arrays, clone, subclass, superclass

Eg:

```
class A
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
}
class B extends A
{
    int new_array[];
}
```

Now here, I want to that new_array in class B should be containing the same elements as array in class A.

**NOTE :**
**I want to copy, but want to take care of that case where when we do any change in the copied array then the change should "not" be reflected in the original array.**

Comment: Why not just inherit `array`?

Comment: How to inherit an array?

Comment: Same way you inherit anything else.

Comment: I would be very kind of you to tell me how to do it. Actually, currently I'm learning Java. So, currently not comfortable with the language.

Comment: Inheritance is covered in so many Java tutorials.  I suggest you start your research there.

Comment: okay. thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Jorvis if you think your question has a good answer its a good idea to mark it as  answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying and surfing the web, I finally managed learned how to copy an array without using loops.
The solution is as follows :

```
class A
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
class B extends A
{
    int copyArray[] = array.clone();
}
```

I found this clone() method really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class A {
  int arrayA[] = {1,2,4,5,3}; //unsorted array
}

public class B extends A {
  int arrayB[];

  public void exampleOfCopySortPrint() {
    arrayB = Arrays.copyOf(arrayA, 5); // copy the values of arrayA into arrayB
    // arrayB is now an entirely new array

    Arrays.sort(arrayB); // this sorts the array from small to large

    // print all elements in arrayB
    for (int i : arrayB) {
      System.out.println(i); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (sorted)
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to also add the field in class B.

If you don't add the modifier public or protected on the array field like `protected int array[];` in class A, make sure you place the 2 classes in the same folder/package.

Comment: Now i want you want to ask one more thing, that suppose I want to sort an array but don't want to perform an any changes in the given array. So, then what to do?

Comment: @Jorvis like so. `Arrays` is a special util class, that contains loads of static methods to manipulate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

class A {

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

}

class B extends A {

```
int new_array[] = array;

public void afterCopyArrayPrint() {
    for (int i : new_array) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

}

public class ArrayTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B ob = new B();
    ob.afterCopyArrayPrint();
}
```

}

Comment: just assign values array to empty array, Data will gets copied into new array variable

Comment: But with your solution, suppose when I want to perform sorting on the given array but want the given array to stay unchanged then your solution of copying won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// TRY THIS
public class Array 
{
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int length = a.length;
}

class Array2 extends Array 
{
    int[] newArray = new int[super.length];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Array obj = new Array();
        Array2 obj2 = new Array2();
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj2.newArray[i] =obj.a[i];
            System.out.println(obj2.newArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```